# Build a buffer in file for stream of TCP packets

Tags: python, tcp, proxy, buffer

I am trying to build a proxy to buffer some packets according to some schedules.

I have two TCP connections, one from host A to the proxy and the other one from the proxy to host B.
The proxy forwards the packets between A and B. The proxy will buffer the packets according to the scheduled instructions. At certain time, it will buffer the packets. After the buffering period is over, it will forward the packets in the buffer and also do its normal forwarding work.
I am using python. Which module would be the best in this situation? I tried pickle but it is difficult to remove and append elements in the file. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason a simple list wouldn't suffice?  Because it would take up too much memory?  Have you considered [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)?

Comment: @jedwards The two TCP connections at the proxy are two separate python scripts. So, I need to store the packets in a separate file. I am not familiar with tempfile. Can tempfile be append and delete partially?

Comment: Append yes, deleting is not as easy, but certainly do-able.

Comment: @jedwards I see. Because after the packets are forwarded, I want to clear up the buffer. That's why I want to delete the content. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: If you want to completely empty the buffer in one go, that's easy, delete the file or open it as `w` then close it.  If you want to delete specific rows one at a time its harder but not impossible -- its usually done by re-writing the entire file with only the lines that you want to keep (either in-place or to a second file, which you then use to replace your original file once the lines are all written)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you join the two scripts into one and just use memory.

If you can't join the scripts for some reason, create a unix-domain socket to pass the raw, binary data directly from one to the other.  These fifos have limited size so you'll still have to do in-memory buffering on one side or another, probably the B side.

If the data is too big for memory, you can write it out to a temporary file and re-read it when it's time to pass it on.  It'll be easiest if the same script both writes and reads the file as then you won't have to guess when to write, advanced to a new file, or deal with separate readers and writers.

Comment: I was trying to do that at first. I had only 3 scripts on A, proxy, and B. However, I ran into the problem of synchronization. I started the proxy as the server to A and A was the sender and the proxy also acted as the sender to B which acted as a server. When I started all 3 scripts (at A, proxy, and B), I needed to make sure B started before the proxy and before A's script. If the timing didn't work out correctly and A waited for too long for the proxy to start receiving packets, it will close the session.

Comment: So, I thought it may be easier to separate the proxy receiving and forwarding script into two.  I know it sounds dumb. 
Any solutions welcome!

Comment: Yes, you'll have to order the startup of A, B, and P or add code to retry after some interval if it's peer is not yet available.

Comment: I see. Let me try that first. Thanks!